# How to correctly reference annotated EJB3 beans from JNDI in WAR-project

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x

We have a multimodule Java EE 5 project running on Weblogic 10.3.x. One module has the EJBs and our batch processor is running from the web-module. Since we don't have CDI in JavaEE5, we have to do a JNDI-lookup on the EJBs. The EJBs are defined with @Stateless on the class and @Remote on the interface.

I have succeeded accessing the EJBs by looking the following string:

```
ejb/batchService#com.example.service.batch.ejb.BatchServiceRemote
```

However, I belive this is highly platformdependent, and I suspect I should have put something inside the web.xml and probably into the weblogic.xml at least in the web-module - maybe even in the EJB module...

Could anyone enlighten me how to do this propperly? Or is this the best way available?

Comment: I use for glassfish '@EJB(name="nice_bean_name", beanInterface=MyInterface.class)'

Answer (score 1):

JNDI format of local bean is

```
java:comp/env/BeanClassName
```

JNDI format for remote bean is

```
mappedName#com.package.BeanClassName
```

for

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "mappedName")
public class BeanClassName  {
```

PS. This format supported by `WebLogic 10.3`. Behaviour of another application servers may be differentю

Answer (score 0):

Prior to EJB 3.1 / EE 6, there are no standardized lookup strings for EJBs.  Since they're not standardized, hard-coding the actual binding name of the EJB does make your project product-specific.

The best solution is to create another level of indirection: declare an `<ejb-local-ref>` in web.xml (or as `@EJB`/`@EJBs` on a servlet or other component class), and then use `java:comp/env/xyz` to lookup the ref.  Then, use platform-specific bindings for the EJB ref.